# match a specific html tag that appears only once in a line

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

how to match this kind of line

```
<p><span class="font7" style="font-weight:bold;">text text text text </span></p>\r\n<p>
```

and at the same time avoid this kind of line

```
<p><span class="font7" style="font-weight:bold;">text text text text </span><span class="font7"> text text text <br/> text text text </span></p>\r\n<p>
```

the problem is that the tag span appears twice in the same line, i want to avoid that.
only wanting if appears once in a line.

```
</span>
```

i have tried this regex

```
<p><span class="font7" style="font-weight:bold;">.+?(?:(?!.+?</span>.+?$)){2}</p>\r\n<p>
```

please help me, if possible in .net, perl or ruby flavor

greetings

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML. Please see the first answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348

Comment: The problem with that answer is that it is funny to those of us who understand the problems of HTML parsing, but meaningless to the novices who don't.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to parse HTML with regular expressions.  You can't do it reliably.  Regular expressions are not up to the task.

You need a proper HTML parser.  It will be an HTML parser that has been well-tested and used by many people, as opposed to whatever regexes you try to cobble together.

Here are some options for [Perl HTML parsers](http://htmlparsing.com/perl.html).  Start there.

Comment: thanks, but already solved the problem by my self, it was not really difficult, even though i think for some harder tasks i would be considering the option you gave.